# What happened to those killed by Thanos before the Snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, after recovering the 6 Stones, Hulk snaps his fingers and brings back all the lost characters but he can’t bring back Black Widow or Gamora as the sacrifices for the Soul Stone are final. However, he explicitly states he tried.

Since those characters had not died because of the snap it’s clear the resurrection part doesn’t need to be limited to just the snapped out people, do we have any information about all the people who died for reasons other than the snap? Were they resurrected too or are they still death?

I’m thinking here of Vision, Loki, the people from Xandar, the Dwarves, all the casualties on the fight with Thanos, etc.

Comment: It has, kinda sorta here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212160/4295 feel free to close it as duplicate as that answers my question.

Comment: Also, Heimdall.

Comment: Voted to leave open, considering what happens with Loki in the film he is somewhat of a special case to the general case asked about here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They stayed dead, Loki, Vision and Heimdall are some of the best examples. Had they come back to life we most certainly would have seen them in the Battle of Earth, however, we did not. Vision even shows up in the "in memorium" video in *Spider-Man: Far From Home*.

Christopher Markus answers is a bit more clearly for these characters stating that they stayed dead.

> **Fandango: The Snap did bring back a lot of our favorite characters. Loki, is he kicking around somewhere? And what about Vision?**
>
> **Christopher Markus:** No, I mean we only brought back the people who were effectively disintegrated by the Snap at the end of Infinity War. Anybody who died over the course of the movie through neck-snapping or stabbing or being thrown off a cliff or having a Mind Stone torn out of their head stayed dead.
>
> <sub>[Fandango, EXCLUSIVE INTERVIEW: THE 'AVENGERS ENDGAME' WRITERS BREAK DOWN THE BIGGEST MOMENTS IN THE MOVIE [SPOILERS!]](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-the-avengers-endgame-writers-break-down-the-biggest-moments-in-the-movie-spoilers-753736?cjid=cj_10369448_8519045_100652X1574804X73c73b54ecf5b15563df9249a5f28527&cjevent=8d368bd7704011e98348002d0a180512)</sub>

Comment: Just a little question more that, I think, doesn't need to be ask as a real question in this SE: what about people that died not at the snap, but because of the snap? Let's say, a bus driver that was snapped, and the passengers inside that couldn't save the bus from going into the car in front of them; or builders that were crushed by the bricks their colleagues were supposed to be lifting? Is it considered as a death by the snap or not?

Comment: @Lyzvaleska I believe it is considered the same case as to those who died before the snap. They weren't victims of the snap itself but because of what the snap caused and so weren't brought back.

Comment: @Lyzvaleska If it makes you feel better the people who died in the Snap related accidents will be fine in the branch universe that endgame Thanos left to go attack the original timeline universe.  That branch universe never had a Snap and Thanos died way sooner.