# Did Thanos somewhat succeed?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-endgame, thanos

Spoiler warning! Though, I think we're at a point where all this is common knowledge?

Anyway, we know (see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217344/what-happened-to-those-killed-by-thanos-before-the-snap)), the Hulk didn't bring back anyone who died **before** or **as a result of** the snap, though he tried with Gamora and Black Widow.

However, nothing is ever said about all those planets and civilisations Thanos wiped out before the snap, manually. Think e.g. of Gamora's family or half the Asgardians. As [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215945) comment points out there's reason to assume their population was **halved again**. So, looking at the example of Drax, it would mean only the one half (1/4) comes back. Right?

Also, just a random other thought: what about animals (that can't talk). Apparently they were also affected by the snap since it's part of *"life"*:

> Thanos wiped out fifty percent of
> **all the living creatures** on Earth.
>
> [...]
>
> I thought by eliminating **half of life**, the other half would thrive.

But were they also brought back? I mean reducing them is one thing, but brining them back? Wouldn't that have devastating effects on the ecosystem? Also, including the micro realm: Bacteria, Microbes, Plankton..

Considering all that, I would say it's fair to say that Thanos to some extend succeeded. Sure, not to the original extend, but considering the many civilisations he wiped out before (at least 3), all the casualties resulting in the snap, and all the environmental impacts.. I feel like it's often overlooked how successful he actually is and how nobody seems to care. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think Thanos was partially successful. Having half of every population die would mean that many more people would die as a result of critical positions (any factories, transportations, medical, etc) being unmanned. Governments may also collapse, wars could start, and people could starve if the half that got snapped just happened to be the people in charge of food production.
But we already know Thanos' plan wasn't very well thought-out if he was truly trying to make the world a better place...

And yes, all living things includes animals, which were also brought back by the hulk. You can hear birds chirping right after he snaps, whereas it was quiet outside before, implying wildlife has returned. Good question!

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input. Also, love the detail about the birds.. did not notice that before.. ;)